# jquery add input by code with call to another function bad quotes concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a TextBox that create dynamically another when user lost focus.

I can create the first dynamic textbox but the second doesn't work because the html generated by jquery don't work.

jQuery

```
function AddTextBox(idnewcontrol, container)
{
    var htmlinner = "<input class='form-control' id='" + idnewcontrol + "'    name='" + idnewcontrol + "' type='text' onblur='AddTextBox   ('"+idnewcontrol+"','" + container + "')'>";
   $('#' + container).append(htmlinner);
};
```

Html generated after first on blur

```
<input class="form-control" id="PollOptions" name="PollOptions" type="text" onblur="AddTextBox(" polloptions','polloptionslist')'="">
```

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes like this \"

Comment: I'd recommend creating a jQuery object instead, as you can assign all those properties in much more readable code.  However, do you realise that this is just going to keep creating a duplicate control over and over again, with the same ID & name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code (escaping the two last double quotes `\"`) and it's work :

```
 var htmlinner = "<input class='form-control' id='" + idnewcontrol + "' name='" + idnewcontrol + "' type='text' onblur=\"AddTextBox('"+idnewcontrol+"','" + container + "')\">";
```

result :

```
 <input class="form-control" id="aaa" name="bbbb" type="text" onblur="AddTextBox('cccc','dddd')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `onblur` attribut, you can use the `live` function:

```
$('.form-control').live('blur', function() {
    var idnewcontrol = $(this).attr('id')+'stuff';

    var htmlinner = "<input class='form-control' id='" + idnewcontrol + "' name='" + idnewcontrol + "' type='text'>";

   $('#polloptionslist').append(htmlinner);
})
```

You only have to change the id and the container with what you want !